# How to find the frequency and type of my current RAM?

Tags: ram

How shall I find out the frequency and type of my current RAM? My OS is Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/q/18372/255443 which has, in my opinion, a better answer.

Answer (score 318, accepted):

This should do:

```
sudo lshw -short -C memory
```

Comment: Only outputs "PCI (sysfs)"

Comment: Wait shortly, it will output more.

Comment: This doesn't display the frequency.

Comment: It should, and it does for me: on my computer, two of the lines read "4GiB DIMM DDR3 Synchronous **1333 MHz** (0.8 ns)" (corresponding to the two RAM slots where I have RAM installed). Did you look closely?

Comment: sudo lshw -C memory > info.txt      Not sure, it won't display on my terminal, but if I pipe it to a file it shows.

Comment: This did not display the frequency for me in Ubuntu 15.04. Likely hardware dependent. Solution by Henrique worked though.

Comment: Don't work in my mint mate 18, the shell would stuck.

Comment: Don't use -short

Comment: If this solution isn't working for you see: https://askubuntu.com/a/1319201/19033

Comment: /system/bin/sh: lshw: not found

Comment: @CSQGB `/system/bin` is not a standard directory for executables on Ubuntu. It sounds like you may working in a BusyBox, possibly on an Android system? This site is about Ubuntu questions. For Android, I would recommend to ask that question on https://android.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 111):

Use the [`lshw`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/lshw.1.html) command with the `memory` class:

```
$ sudo lshw -C memory
  # Some things about firmware and caches
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 13
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 8GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM [empty]
          product: [Empty]
          vendor: [Empty]
          physical id: 0
          serial: [Empty]
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
     *-bank:1
          description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
          product: M471B5273DH0-CK0
          vendor: Samsung
          physical id: 1
          serial: 34A8C7AF
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
     # More banks.
```

As you can see, I'm using DDR3 1600MHz RAM.

Another option is [`dmidecode`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/dmidecode.8.html):

```
$ sudo dmidecode -t memory
# dmidecode 2.9
SMBIOS 2.5 present.

Handle 0x003B, DMI type 16, 15 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: Multi-bit ECC
    Maximum Capacity: Unknown
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 8

Handle 0x003D, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x003B
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM_A1
    Bank Locator: NODE 0 CHANNEL 0 DIMM 0
    Type: Other
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1067 MHz (0.9 ns)
    Manufacturer: 0x0198
    Serial Number: 0xB12A9593
    Asset Tag: Unknown
    Part Number: 9965426-037.A00LF 
# more such devices
```

This is for a server with ECC memory (as can be seen from the `Error Correction Type` field and [the difference between `Data Width` and `Total Width`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10510/how-to-detect-memory-type-under-linux)).

Both tools are dependencies of the `ubuntu-standard` package and should be available by default on all Ubuntu systems. There used to be another tool called `hwinfo`, which is no longer available for Ubuntu since 13.10.

Comment: For me too: DDR3 1600 MHz. So does that mean both modules are the same type and I'm getting best performance?

Comment: @arno Yes, as far as I can tell. There's also a recommendation that modules should be in parallel banks (0/2/4, 1/3/5, etc.) for best performance - but I don't know if that's myth or fact.

Comment: I am getting this output: `Configured Memory Speed: 1600 MT/s`. Is this same as 1600 MHz?

Comment: @YogiKatba seems so (at least, looking at https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/462465-mts-mhz/?do=findComment&comment=6206851)

Comment: is there a way to show all this extended info, but only for `*-memory` / `*-bank:#`? there's lot of trash like `*-cache#` or `*-firmware` (that I don't want to see if I'm checking RAM)

Answer (score 40):

I could only get this info with `dmidecode`, but rather than grepping, it's cleaner to use the right type:

```
sudo dmidecode --type memory
```

Comment: Good answer, and I think this is easier to read:`sudo dmidecode -t memory | less -N`

Comment: This also shows information about the DIMMs being Registered or Unbuffered

Answer (score 25):

This will give you all information you may want, probably:

```
sudo dmidecode | grep -A 15 Memory
```

Comment: Yes it shows. Mine for exemple is shown as:

Speed: 1333 MHz
Just after Type Detail.

Comment: dmidecode returns information from the bios... Maybe you have a problem with your bios... Don't know.

Comment: This was the only command that shows the frequency of my generic DRAM

Comment: Thanks this was the perfect answer for me.I got all the details..:)

Answer (score 15):

Try Hard info, for install run in terminal : `sudo apt-get install hardinfo`
It has interface, and it's simple to use. )

Comment: Doesn't work for me, "Memory SPD" stays empty, even after the `sudo modprobe eeprom` as adviced e.g. [here](https://github.com/lpereira/hardinfo/issues/426). This is probably due to my Ubuntu having an old version, but prepare to jump through some hoops in the hope that it will work, is all I'm saying.

Answer (score 1):

Above answers are correct; I just wanted to add further by piping the output of command to grep for Type and speed.

```
sudo dmidecode --type memory | grep -m2 Type
```

FYI: T in Type must be capital.

This might give either Type: DDR4 OR Type: DDR3

for speed use

```
sudo dmidecode --type memory | grep -m1 Speed
```

FYI: -m option of grep is used to limit the number of lines; for example -m2 means 2 lines.

Comment: For me it outputs `Speed: Unknown`. I had to use `-m4` to display one line per one ram slot. Now it shows the speeds.

Answer (score 1):

**REST OF ANSWERS**

The **rest of methods** don't always work, reporting the speed as unknown. Here's one way that never fails.

---

**REQUIRED SOFTWARE**

Install **i2c-tools**.

---

**MEMORY BANDWIDTH**

Read the value from the **RAM eeprom** with:

> sudo modprobe eeprom && decode-dimms | grep speed | rev | cut --delimiter=" " --fields=2,3 | rev; sudo modprobe --remove eeprom

The value is returned in **MT/s**.

---

**MEMORY FREQUENCY**

If you want the value in **MHz** just divide the previous result by the number of channels the RAM module has, which you can get with:

> sudo modprobe eeprom && decode-dimms | grep Ranks | rev | cut --delimiter=" " --fields=1 | rev; sudo modprobe --remove eeprom

---

**MISCONFIGURED MOTHERBOARD**

Note this is the **speed of the module**, not the speed that the motherboard is configured and capable to use.

For checking if the speed is **misconfigured** in the motherboard access the BIOS or **UEFI**, as explained in your motherboard manual.

Comment: it's weird as you just said to get the bus clock (MHz/s) , i should divide the data rate (Mt/s) by two , but the output of `lshw -short -C memory` shows bus clock equal to the `dmidecode -t memory` data rate which is in 1333MHz and 1333MT/s respectively

Comment: @polendina What do you get if you do: `sudo modprobe eeprom && decode-dimms | grep Ranks | rev | cut --delimiter=" " --fields=1 | rev; sudo modprobe --remove eeprom`

Comment: four 1s on four separate lines

Comment: @polendina That means your RAM is single channel, while mine was dual channel. I have edited my response to be applicable to any amount of channels. Thanks for pointing this out 

Answer (score 0):

Most of these answers will just give you the nominal clock speed of the memory.
It may not be the actual clock speed.

The canonical method is to boot Memtest or if you are so endowed, boot Windows and use CPU-Z.

You can trust BIOS, you can trust Memtest. There are an enormous number of low cost boxes fitted with 1333MHz DDR3 that is actually clocked at 1066MHz. Both DMI decode and LSHW may be deceptive.